# Export/Stream Mac Terminal Output To File

Tags: macos, terminal

I am running a php script on my Mac terminal which takes hours and hours to run. It consumes memory very quickly, and after a while the scroll back gets truncated. Settings on the Terminal: Scrollback - Limit to available memory.

Is there a way to automatically stream (or just save) the output into a file (whether on local disk or on external harddrive). Also I realise the memory doesn't get cleared until I restart my com (my Finder indicates 0 space on my harddrive after a while but when I restart my com it becomes 20GB). Is there a way to clear this once my output is saved?

It will be nice to include the timestamp as well in the file.

Comment: Either use output redirection to log to a file, or if you want to still see the output as well as log to a file then use [tee](https://linux.die.net/man/1/tee).

Answer (score 3):

Run your PHP script in the background (or even with `nohup` as well, if you want to be able to log out and leave it running), and save your output to a log file on disk like this:

```
someScript.php > log.txt &
```

Now, if you want to watch the log file growing at a later point, just use the `-f` option to `tail` to *follow* the log:

```
tail -f log.txt
```

If you see that all is well and the job is still running, press <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> and you will stop following it but the job will continue. If you want another look later, just run `tail` again.

If you want to see if your script has passed, say `"PHASE 2"`, just `grep` for that in the log file:

```
grep "PHASE 2" log.txt
```

---

If you want to timestamp the lines, I would suggest you use the `ts` utility which is part of *moreutils*, so hoping you use **homebrew** to manage packages (as any sensible Mac user does), you would install it with:

```
brew install moreutils
```

Then you could do:

```
someScript.php | ts > log.txt &
```